# category keyword filter vuejs

Tags: arrays, filter, vuejs2, categories, keyword

Hey guys I have a fiddle that shows the code for my app I am trying to filter each video based on what category or keyword is clicked. I have it pretty well working except when I keep getting duplicates. For example my milkyway video is associated to the holiday, sports and misc categories so instead of just showing one milkyway when these categories are clicked I get three.

I have a data property that called filteredTemplateArray it looks like this.

```
    filteredTemplateArray:Array[1]
0:Object
categoryArray:Array[3]
0:"Misc"
1:"Holiday"
2:"Sports"
dateAdded:"2018-10-01 17:54:22"
id:"233"
itemId:"fb41a01641bb2e769db412d3b21c2e3e"
itemName:"test"
keywordArray:Array[2]
0:"Snow"
1:"LensFlare"
projectPath:"M:/Projects/Generics/uploads/testLocation"
renderTime:"4"
stillImageLocation:"0.13"
tested:"0"
thumbName:"TEST"
```

when there objects with the same id in them I would like to filter out the duplicates. heres a link to my fiddle thanks https://jsfiddle.net/rshba6jz/

Comment: easy approach is to use a `Set` and then `Array.from()` to render

Comment: can you send me an example